# Кастомный JSON на Rails для Js - плагина

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Использую gem awesome_nested_set + jquery.hierSelect.js

Мне нужно получить для плагина c Rails-сервера json вида:

```
{
  '1':{
        'name': "NAME",
        '2':{
              'name':'ChildrenNAME'
            }
      }
}


Hash[Category.select("id,name").all.map { |u| [u.id, u.name ] } ].to_json
```

Так я получаю коллекцию без u.children, как сюда добавить детей для коллекции? 
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Структура json точно правильная? есть подозрение что вложенный `"2":{...}` не получится с использованием указанного кода. Если правильная то нужно более подробное описание структуры.

Comment: И ещё, из вопроса непонятно куда и как должны попадать `u.children`